# Extract word from string using grep/sed/awk

Tags: command-line, bash, grep, sed, awk

I have a string

```
00:28:04 /usr/lib/jvm/jre/bin/java -DJDBC_CONNECTION_STRING= -Dspring.profiles.active=qa -XX:MaxPermSize=256
```

and want to extract the word `qa` that follows `-Dspring.profiles.active`.

I have the string save in a file text.txt just to demo on it.

When I do

```
grep -r -o "spring.profiles.active=" text.txt
```

The result is `spring.profiles.active=`

This word does not always be `qa`, it could be `prod` or `dev`.

What I'd like to do is find the word `spring.profiles.active` and **after** the `=` extract that word.

I would like to shell script this because I use the **word** to configure other items on the server.

Is this possible and if so, how do I do it.

Comment: I'm guessing there have been meta conversations about this already, but this question is completely non-specific to Ubuntu. Why is it here instead of  http://unix.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: @TonyAdams Yes there have: text-processing questions have been indirectly covered [here](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14123/is-ask-ubuntu-about-solving-actual-problems), and anyway de-facto they have been always considered on-topic and never closed / migrated; on the Ubuntu-specificness, that has been covered multiple times, twice just recently [here](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14663/are-non-ubuntu-spefic-questions-allowed) and in the duplicate and once [here](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/47/how-do-we-tell-if-a-question-belongs-here-or-rather-at-stackoverflow-superuser).

Comment: good question! :D

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use `grep` with PCRE (`-P`):

```
grep -Po 'spring.profiles.active=\K[^ ]+' <<<'.....string.....'
```

- `spring.profiles.active=` will match this substring literally, `\K` will discard the match
- `[^ ]+` will select the desired portion i.e. the portion after `spring.profiles.active=`, till the next space

For a file:

```
grep -Po 'spring.profiles.active=\K[^ ]+' file.txt
```

**Example:**

```
% grep -Po 'spring.profiles.active=\K[^ ]+' <<<'00:28:04 /usr/lib/jvm/jre/bin/java -DJDBC_CONNECTION_STRING= -Dspring.profiles.active=qa -XX:MaxPermSize=256'
qa
```

---

`sed` would take similar logic:

```
sed -r 's/.*spring.profiles.active=([^ ]+).*/\1/' <<<'.....string.....'
```

**Example:**

```
% sed -r 's/.*spring.profiles.active=([^ ]+).*/\1/' <<<'00:28:04 /usr/lib/jvm/jre/bin/java -DJDBC_CONNECTION_STRING= -Dspring.profiles.active=qa -XX:MaxPermSize=256'
qa
```

**Handling errors:**

In your script you may want to handle the case where there is no match, in other words where your original string does not contain `spring.profiles.active=`. In the above `sed` example, you obtain the whole original string, which could create problems:

```
% var="$(sed -r 's/.*spring.profiles.active=([^ ]+).*/\1/' <<<'00:28:04 /usr/lib/jvm/jre/bin/java -DJDBC_CONNECTION_STRING= -XX:MaxPermSize=256')"
% echo $var
00:28:04 /usr/lib/jvm/jre/bin/java -DJDBC_CONNECTION_STRING= -XX:MaxPermSize=256
```

If you prefer to obtain the empty string when there is no match, add the `-n` option to the `sed` command and the `p` option to the `sed` `s` command, like this:

```
% var="$(sed -rn 's/.*spring.profiles.active=([^ ]+).*/\1/p' <<<'00:28:04 /usr/lib/jvm/jre/bin/java -DJDBC_CONNECTION_STRING= -XX:MaxPermSize=256')"
% echo $var

% var="$(sed -rn 's/.*spring.profiles.active=([^ ]+).*/\1/p' <<<'00:28:04 /usr/lib/jvm/jre/bin/java -DJDBC_CONNECTION_STRING= -Dspring.profiles.active=qa -XX:MaxPermSize=256')"
% echo $var
qa
```

Then you can test if $var is empty or not.

Comment: Thanks @heemay, works perfect. now I just need to script that. I will mark it as answered

Comment: @heemay would you know how I could scripted this. I have it in a script and when it runs it return qa. I want to save the result in a variable called env and then  to compare that to something like. If [ env == qa ]; then //DO Something... else Do Something...

Comment: @Gman Yeah.. just use command substitution: `var="$(grep -Po 'spring.profiles.active=\K[^ ]+' file.txt)"` replace `file.txt` with `<<<'...string...'` if input is a string, not a file..then you can do `if [ "$var" = 'qa' ]; then do something; else do something; fi`

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`

```
awk -F"-Dspring.profiles.active=" '{sub(/ .*/,"",$2);print $2}' <<<'your_string'
```

or

```
awk -F"-Dspring.profiles.active=" '{sub(/ .*/,"",$2);print $2}' your_file
```

---

*Example*

```
% awk -F"-Dspring.profiles.active=" '{sub(/ .*/,"",$2);print $2}' <<<'00:28:04 /usr/lib/jvm/jre/bin/java -DJDBC_CONNECTION_STRING= -Dspring.profiles.active=qa -XX:MaxPermSize=256'
qa
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll throw a Perl one in the mix:

```
<<<'string' perl -lane '$F[3]=~s/.*?=//;print($F[3])'
```

- `-l`: enables automatic line-ending processing. It has two separate effects. First, it automatically chomps $/ (the input record separator) when used with -n or -p. Second, it assigns $\ (the output record separator) to have the value of octnum so that any print statements will have that separator added back on. If octnum is omitted, sets $\ to the current value of $/.
- `-a`: turns on autosplit mode when used with a -n or -p. An implicit split command to the @F array is done as the first thing inside the implicit while loop produced by the -n or -p.
- `n`: causes Perl to assume the following loop around your program, which makes it iterate over filename arguments somewhat like sed -n or awk:

  ```
  LINE:
    while (<>) {
        ...             # your program goes here
    }
  ```
- `-e`: may be used to enter one line of program.

```
% <<<'00:28:04 /usr/lib/jvm/jre/bin/java -DJDBC_CONNECTION_STRING= -Dspring.profiles.active=qa -XX:MaxPermSize=256' perl -lane '$F[3]=~s/.*?=//;print($F[3])'
qa
```

Comment: orginal regex can be used also like this: `perl -nle '/spring.profiles.active=\K([^ ]+)/ && print $1' <<<'00:28:04 /usr/lib/jvm/jre/bin/java -DJDBC_CONNECTION_STRING= -Dspring.profiles.active=qa -XX:MaxPermSize=256'`